# How do i initialize this 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am looking for declaring the type of 2D array that can hold only 3 distinct values in the below code.

What could be the type of the 2D array that can take least memory for each cell and hold one of the 3 distinct values? I would then initialise such array using for-loop.

```
class Grid{
    X[][] twoDimArray = new X[3][3];

    Grid(){

    }

    void printElements(){
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's only 3 distinct values, you should probably use an `enum`.

Comment: @August Can we have constructors in `enum`?

Comment: Yes, enums support constructors, methods, and fields too.

Comment: @August So, when they support all three, how do u differentiate with `class` in usage? i understand the above example above where enum is more appropriate, but in general?

Comment: Enums should be used when you need a set of constants: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For three values, an `enum` is very compelling;

```
enum ExampleEnum {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
        case ONE:
            return "One";
        case TWO:
            return "Two";
        default:
            return "Three";
        }
    }
}
```

Then your array declaration might look like,

```
ExampleEnum[][] twoDimArray = new ExampleEnum[3][3];
```

And you could use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) for output like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDimArray));
```

Comment: One supplement query, `each declared field is also an instance of the enum` How do i understand this compared to `class`?

Comment: @overexchange Each `enum` is a constant, there are only three distinct instances of your analogous `class`.

Comment: So, `enum` Usage is not about less memory usage but about more intuitive representation of using 3 distinct elements. In C programming, we could have more control on decreasing memory usage by using bit syntax. am i correct?

Comment: @overexchange Java [`Enum` types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) are *very* similar to C style enum(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you need three distinct values, byte[][] is probably the most efficient you can get memory wise.

Answer (score 1):

If, just if, you would need to reduce resource usage, one could store the entire grid in an int, two bits per diagram position, 9 positions: 18 bits.

```
int diagram;

int getValue(int x, int y) {
    int i = 2*(x + 3*y);
    return (diagram >>> i) & 0x3;
}

void setValue(int x, int y, int value) {
    int i = 2*(x + 3*y);
    int mask = 0x3 << i;
    diagram &= ~mask;
    diagram |= value << i;
}
```