# How do i compare enum types post Java 5.0?

Tags: java, enums

In continuation with [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27653714/how-do-i-initialize-this-2d-array-in-java), I would like to compare the enum constants.

I learnt that: In Java 5.0, the enum keyword is introduced as a special type of class that always extends `java.lang.Enum`. This class already has `equals()` method that compares the reference(`this == obj`).

```
enum TicTacToe{
    X, O, NULL;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        switch(this){
        case X:
            return "X";
        case O:
            return "O";
        default:
            return "NULL";

        }
    }

}

class Grid{
    TicTacToe[][] twoDimArray = new TicTacToe[3][3];

    Grid(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                twoDimArray[i][j] = TicTacToe.NULL; 
            }
        }
    }

    int chooseMove(boolean side){
        if(this.gameDone()){

        }else{

        }
        return 0; // give solution
    }

    boolean gameDone(){
        // Compare the elements in 2D array
        return true; // give solution
    }

    void printElements(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            System.out.println(" " + twoDimArray[i][0] + " | " + twoDimArray[i][1] + " | " + twoDimArray[i][2]);
            if(i != 2)
                System.out.println("------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

Before i compare the values in `gameDone()` method above, I would like to understand, what exactly are we doing , when we say, `twoDimArray[i][j] = TicTacToe.NULL;` Are we creating an object of enum type and assigning to each element in the array?

How do i compare these elements in the array? Because `equals()` method expects reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare enum types, you can simply use `yourVariable == SomeEnumType`.

For example:

```
if (enumType == TicTacToe.NULL) {
  // Enum type is NULL!
}
```

You can also implement a new `equals` method, overriding equals() of the superclass `Enum`. If you don't, then doing `variable.equals(EnumType)` will be the same as `variable == EnumType`.

Comment: what about `equals()` method in `java.lang.Enum` that `enum` keyword extends? when do we use this method?

Comment: You can implement a new `equals` method, overriding equals() of the superclass `Enum`. If you don't, then doing `variable.equals(EnumType)` will be the same as `variable == EnumType`.

Comment: yes, But when default `equals()`method says `(this == obj)` in `java.lang.Enum`, Is it comparing references? This is the reason am asking that, what exactly are we doing when we say:  `twoDimArray[i][j] = TicTacToe.NULL;` Are we internally creating object of reference type `class Enum` and then assigning it?

Comment: Enumeration contents will be created only one time (per `ClassLoader`, I think), so their references will ALWAYS be the same. On Java, using `someObject == otherObject` is the same thing as `someObject.hashCode() == otherObject.hashCode()`, and the `default hashCode` of an object is defined when they are created. So, the objects of an enum are created once only. You can assign them when and where you want, they all will be the same object.

Comment: Oh ok, so in this statement when am assigning `twoDimArray[i][j] = TicTacToe.NULL;` am actually assigning single object 9 times in the above code, correct? Any reference to your point:"per ClassLoader"?

Comment: Exact. And about the ClassLoader, I'm not sure, but the enumeration objects can be re-created when you load the enumeration from within another ClassLoader (other than the default one), like, for example, URLClassLoader. It's not something that you would probably need to worry about.

Comment: Can we have constructors in enum types?

Comment: Yes. I made an example for you: http://pastebin.com/VKyrfD2k. Remember that enum constructors MUST be private.